# Append HTML code to DOMDocument in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have two pieces of HTML code (both can be contain many tags and sub-tags). I iterate through first one DOMDocument and DOMXPath and count text length inside each tag. When the counter is more than X, I want to add second HTML to current node in first HTML. I use this code but I don't know how to use appenChild or similar functions to append my HTML.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($HTML1);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$characterCounter = 0;

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//*[count(*) = 0]') as $node) 
{
    $characterCounter += strlen($node->nodeValue);
    if($characterCounter > 150) 
    { 
         //Here I have to append second HTML but it does not append
         $node->appendChild($doc->createTextNode($HTML2));
         break;
    }
}

$doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: are you certain that the append is actually called?

Comment: the HTML get added to the node as a text! not as HTML.

Comment: that's not surprising, since you append a **TextNode**. Technically, you should parse `$HTML2` as well (into a new `DOMDocument`) and append the root node instead of the raw text. Since `DOMDocument` is a `DOMNode` as well, this should work.